# JQuery resizable with a knob

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using [`jQuery-ui Resizable`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable/resizable#options) - and i want to use a knob instead of the borders (my knob is a button in the bottom right).

I see that in options I have a `KnobHandles`, that I have to set to `true`.

Where do I set my handle? I tried to set it in the handles option but it is not working.

Below is my code:

```
window.resizable({
    'handles':'handler-resize',
    'knobHandles': true
});
```

UPDATE: just noticed that the knobhandles is some default stuff. I want to resize it with a customized button, is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

i did it, i just had to style the knobs...

btw: handles must come with direction like s, n, se, ...

Answer (score 1):

Each handle string (if specified) should be in the form of a jQuery selector matching the child element of the resizable to use as the handle.

So I think you want something like:

```
'handles': '.handler-size'
```